# In a sentence of imperative mood, can the verb end in -ing?

Tags: sentence, imperatives

You might text these to someone:

Walking to school.

Driving there.

I believe that the main use of this type of sentence would be to describe what you yourself are doing in that moment. You might write this on a dating profile:

Seeking openminded, Christian, bowling fans.

So, my question is, are these full sentences that should start with a capital letter and then be terminated with a period? There are no subjects, and unlike usual imperatives, they don't give commands . . .

Comment: Welcome: Please check the meaning of 'imperative'.  These aren't.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you're right...they are declaratives.

Comment: abbreviated declaratives to be exact, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. None of your examples are in imperative mood.
2. They aren't full grammatical sentences. This abbreviated form is often used as a heading, a caption or an update on social media.
3. The full version would be, "I am walking to school", "I am driving there", "I am seeking openminded, Christian, bowling fans."
4. If the first one is a caption -- say of a photograph, the unabbreviated form depends on the subject matter. For example: "This is me walking to school" or "This is a picture of some children walking to school."  Both could be abbreviated to "Walking to school."